# How to shorten the package in Android Studio if you have multiple modules in the project?

Tags: android, android-studio

My app project consists of many modules:

```
app
compnent_*
compnent_*
compnent_*
compnent_*
compnent_*
feature_*
feature_*
feature_*
... and so on
```

In Android Studio it's easy to rename the app package

E.g. we can easily change from `com.bestapp.android` to `com.amazingapp.android`

It will suggest to automatically rename all packages in all files/classes/manifest of all modules, no headache at all for developers

But what if I need to shorten the package, e.g. from `com.the.bestapp.android` to `com.bestapp.android`?

I also tried to drag and drop `bestapp` folder in "app" module from `the` folder to `com` folder and it suggested to do it for all modules, I clicked yes, it worked BUT!

It moved all classes (files) to app module, so all files from other modules has been moved to app module. Canceled this action and I'm trying to find another solution.

I can manually drag 'n drop for all folders, but there are too much folders

Mb is there any script for this has been created? Or other solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I decided to create a Kotlin/JVM program to do it:

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils
import org.apache.commons.io.filefilter.TrueFileFilter
import java.io.File

fun main() {
    val projectDir = File("D:\\projects\\app_project")

    val dirs = FileUtils.listFilesAndDirs(
        projectDir,
        TrueFileFilter.INSTANCE,
        TrueFileFilter.INSTANCE
    ).filter {
        it.absolutePath.endsWith("com\\the\\bestapp")
    }

    println(dirs.joinToString("\n"))

    val dirsToDelete = dirs.map { it.parentFile }

    dirs.forEach {
        FileUtils.moveDirectoryToDirectory(it, it.parentFile.parentFile, false) // move "bestapp" to "com" folder
    }

    dirsToDelete.forEach {
        it.delete()
    }
}
```

So now it's `com.bestapp.android` instead of `com.the.bestapp.android` - for folders

Works great

But don't forget to rename packages in files (.java, .kt, .xml), it can be easily done by "Replace All" text feature using Notepad++ or Android Studio:

Replace all `com.the.bestapp.android` matched strings to `com.bestapp.android`